# MVC application fails with 404 errors after Web Deploy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, msbuild, web-deployment, antivirus

Sometimes, when I publish an ASP.NET MVC application and copy the files to the production server, I receive 404 errors.  When I examined the differences between the newly published site and old site, I find that a number of files are missing, including App_global.asax.dll and App_global.asax.compiled.

This happen with Visual Studio 2015 and previous versions.  Previous publications were successful, but this seems to be intermittent.  No errors are generated during the build process whatsoever.  Both publishing via MSBuild and publishing via Visual Studio both seem to have the same problem.  Some days, the system will build just fine.  Some days, it won't.   This seems to happen most when I delete the contents of the package directory before publication.

A simple, sample MSBuild command.  This is a very simply one-site .csproj file.

```
MSBuild.exe \MyProject.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=Prod
```

The publish rofile:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>False</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>True</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <publishUrl>C:\packages\MyProject</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <PrecompileBeforePublish>True</PrecompileBeforePublish>
    <EnableUpdateable>False</EnableUpdateable>
    <DebugSymbols>False</DebugSymbols>
    <WDPMergeOption>DonotMerge</WDPMergeOption>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I burned so much time on this issue, I had to share.

This was caused my the McAfee On-Access Virus Scanner interfering with my publication process.  Disabling the service (which it turns out my company allows me to **temporarily** do) completely resolves this problem.

I *think* that this problem is least likely to recur when you set `DeleteExistingFiles` to `false`, because the AV scanner has already seen the files before.  That's just a theory.

Watch out for this behavior.